# How can I parse markdown inside json

Tags: php, json, markdown

I have a JSON like below format.

```json
{
  "title": "Title",
  "content": "Content in **Markdown**"
}
```

Which could be queried if decoded as `$json->title;` and `$json->content;`,
I want to turn the content which is in Markdown to HTML,
I use Parsedown for this work.

```php
<?php
include 'Parsedown.php';

$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
$file = file_get_contents('file.json');
$file = json_decode($file);
$Parsedown->text($file->content);

echo $file->content;
```

But still things appear not as expected.

Comment: ___But still things appear not as expected.___ How do they appear? How did you expect them to appear??

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation? I guess not!! I just did :) and therefore - Try `echo $Parsedown->text($file->content);` or maybe `$file->content = $Parsedown->text($file->content);` as that method returns the result of the parse

Comment: It still return the non-parsed plain text

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the exact output (including var type) of `$file->content` is? `var_dump($file->content)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are still not working then you are still not calling it correctly

```
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
$file = file_get_contents('file.json');

$file = json_decode($file);
$file->content = $Parsedown->text($file->content);

echo $file->content;
```

The RESULT

```
<p>Content in <strong>Markdown</strong></p>
```